# Does anyone know how to fix the blocks turning purple when I import my minecraft world (.obj)?

Tags: modeling, materials, import

[image]
[image]

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Can you check that the paths in the .mtl file match where the textures are on your computer?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2IX1cx4 Right here

Answer (score 0):

Purple color (instead of expected shading) = missing texture. Meaning, you have to locate the texture and reapply it to your mesh manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file → External Data → Find missing Files

[image: demo pic]

Then navigate to the folder containing all your texture files and click the top right <kbd>Find missing files</kbd> button.

It should rebuild the paths of your files. A message in the info bar should indicate how much files have been found or are still missing.

If all your textures have been found but still display purple, then it might be that you need to reassign the textures to the corresponding materials.
You can do that in Cycles using the node editor.